# Where to put NSSort Descriptor when loading Tableview from NSArray using reloadData in Objective-C

Tags: ios, arrays, nssortdescriptor

I am loading a tableview from an NSArray as opposed to an NSFetchedResultsController. When I want to sort or filter a table using NSFetchedResultsController, I just put the sort logic in the -NSFetchedResultsController delegate method.

However, in the present case, I want to sort the tableview displaying an array using reloadData. I know reloadData calls the cellForRowAtIndexPath method.  Is that where I should try to put the logic for the sort?

Since I don't think you can modify the delegate method's signature, I imagine I would have to have an instance variable carry the type of sort to do and after consulting it, sort the array at the beginning of the CellForRowAtIndexPath so that might work but it seems clumsy.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if ([self.sortType intValue==1) {
NSSortDescriptor *sd = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"lastName" ascending:YES];
data = [data sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sd]];
} 
//get cell
//assign object in data array to cell
}
```

Is that the right way to do the sort or is there a better way?

Comment: No, *When I want to sort or filter a table using NSFetchedResultsController*, I put the sort logic in the **NSPredicate of the controller**. In your case sort the array outside of any datasource and delegate method right before calling `reloadData()`

Comment: Ok. Thx! I'll create a separate method for sorting and call it first.